# Floating columns around youtube iframe

Tags: css, iframe

How could I float columns around a youtube video iframe?
This is the HTML code:

```
        <div id="content"> 
            <div class="column">
                <div class="column_header">Lorem ipsum</div>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... 
                <br/><br/>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <div class="column_header">Proin lacus ex</div>
                Proin lacus ex...
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <div class="column_header">Duis lacus lectus</div>
                Duis lacus lectus... 
            </div>
            <div class="ytvid">
                <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2rGGw0cJjYg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#content{
    clear: both;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-top: 0;
    border-top: 20px solid #58AB27;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.column{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    max-width: 30%;
    min-width: 300px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px;
}

.column_header{
    font-size: 150%;
    line-height: 2em;
}
```

The length of the content of the columns may change. Now for example I get something like this:
[image: what I have now]

I would like the youtube iframe to take the empty space under the column 1 and column 2. So I would like to get something like this:

[image: what I would like to see]

Or (by changing the column content) something like this:[image: or this]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is your answer: [Live example on the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gcxh8ogp/1/)

```css
#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
}

#right {
    float: right;
    width: 40%;
    background: yellow;
}

#left {
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
    background: red;
}

.col {
    float:left;
    width: 50%;
}

.col-video {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: pink;
}

.purple {
    background-color: purple;
    height: 150px;
}
.blue {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100px;
}
.green {
    background-color: green;
    height: 250px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">
        <div class="col purple">
            col1
        </div>
        <div class="col blue">
            col1
        </div>
        <div class="col-video">
            col-video
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <div class="col green">
            col2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide above views with two different ways:

- Create a div and put col 1, col 2 and "youtube frame div" into the
  div.
- Set `position` of the container elements as `absolute` and also, set `left` and `top`
  values for each div.